# How to get location (x,y) of UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, location, coordinates, gravity

I have a falling UIView object, and I'm  trying to get the current location of it. I know that its possible to get the original location, but how can i get the current location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! When a uiview is being moved as part of an animation you can get details about its current state by looking at the presentation layer e.g.

```
myView.layer.presentationLayer.center
```

will return a CGPoint with the current location.